# Google Analytics (Android) : use same UA-XXXX for two different apps ? (free and paid version for example)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics

I want to use the same UA for the free and paid version of my Android app. One of these apps has for bundle name com.mycompany.freeapp, the other one com.mycompany.paidapp

I don't want to create two different UA.

Is it possible with the lastest Google Analytics API ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

yes

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

select the same Property in "Choose services"